# How can I Pass a URL Filter to Publish to Web Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

how to pass parameter through "publish to web" URL in power bi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This use of URL filters in publish to web is not supported. You can only use this in an embedded context. The MS documentation outlines the limits [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#considerations-and-troubleshooting) under the embedding scenarios section.